# Validity of Probability Density Function with Negative Values

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was given the following PDF in an exam:

[image: The PDF in question]

We had to calculate the constant $k$ our-self by taking the total integral of $f(x)$ to be 1 and I found k to be $\frac{3}{4}$. The graph of the PDF and the CDF with $k = \frac{3}{4}$:

[image: The graph of f(x)]
[image: The graph of F(x)]

I am quite confused as the PDF produce negative value which could give a negative probability and give a CDF with value higher than 1. Is the PDF valid? If so, then what should be done with the negative probabilities?

Comment: No - a density cannot be negative and a CDF cannot decline.  Your integral also looks strange in the interval $(1,2]$

Comment: That's not even the weirdest part. The CDF exceed 1 in some part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your text (probabily they want you reasoning) the given  pdf is not always $\geq 0$ thus the support must be truncated in the following way

$$f(x)=k(1-x-x^2)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-1;(\sqrt{5}-1)/2)}(x)$$

with this new pdf the constant is

$$k=\frac{12}{7+5\sqrt{5}}$$

Now you can proceed accordingly

---

this is the drawing of your pdf

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the support is truncated?

Comment: @MichaelTeguhLaksana: as per definition, the integral of the pdf must be 1 but there is another condition: $f(x)\geq 0$, $\forall x$. Look at your drawing and waste the interval where $1-x-x^2<0$ then calculate k. By the way did you forget to accept my answer?